# Removing leading zeroes and the string before Hyphen

Tags: c#

How can I perform multiple formatting to a string?

for e.g. doing in the following way doesn't work.

```
var Id = (from p in db.vwIds.Where(p => p.OperationalNumber.Substring(p.OperationalNumber.IndexOf("-") + 1).TrimStart('0')  == id)
                              group p by p.ID into g
                              select g.Key).ToList();
```

Can I not perform more than one actions on a string?

By doesn't work I mean its not pulling Id's from "vwIds". When I hard-code the value of id to "001" and remove the ".TrimStart('0') " it pulls in the Ids, not otherwise.

Basically the id I am passing is a number without leading zeroes, e.g. "1", "2", "112" etc
And Ids present in vwIds are of format: "JEE - 001", "Dee - 002" etc.

Comment: "doesn't work." What doesn't work about it?  It looks perfectly correct to me.  If it doesn't do what you want it to do then you need to describe what you want it to do.  (Ideally with sample inputs and current/desired outputs)

Comment: Always describe "doesn't work". I can't tell if it doesn't compile or produces the wrong results or ...

Comment: @Servy, you're correct, I was reading the code incorrectly. =)

Comment: @Servy I have updated the question above

Comment: An example of the strings would have been nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I hard-code the value of id to "001"

If you're hard coding `id` to "001" the it will never be equal to any ID that has had `.TrimStart('0')` called on it.  Let's assume for a moment that `p.OperationalNumber.IndexOf("-") + 1)` evaluates to "001".  Calling "trimstart" on it will turn it into "1".  "1" is not equal to "001", so it isn't included.

My guess is you need to call `.TrimStart('0')` on ID as well, or better yet, parse both strings into numbers and then compare their numeric value, rather than their string value.

Comment: You got it wrong, I try to remove the leading zeroes when I compare to my id, which doesnt work. When I declare a variable and hard code the value of id to be "001" and remove the "TrimStart('0')" from the code, then it works. Hope its not confusing you

Answer (score 0):

you can get what you want using multiple where clauses, I've tried this its working perfectly

```
        var id = db.vwIds.Where(p => p.OperationalNumber.Contains('-'))
            .Where(p => p.OperationalNumber.Replace(" ", "").Split('-')[1].TrimStart('0') == "23")
            .GroupBy(p => p.ID).Select(g => g.Key);
```

`.Contains('-')` verifies that you have the correct format 'xxx - yyyy'

`Replace(" ", "")` removes white spaces

Another thing, its better to parse your id not to compare it to a string, if you are sure that all your OperationalNumbers contains an int you don't need to trim nor to replace(" ","")

```
        var id = vwIds.Where(p => p.OperationalNumber.Contains('-'))
            .Where(p =>int.Parse(p.OperationalNumber.Split('-')[1]) == 23)
            .GroupBy(p => p.ID).Select(g => g.Key);
```